# Setting ngif conditions with 2 data sets at once

Tags: angular

Wondered if there is any way of blending ngfor / ngif directives? Let me explain...

```
<div *ngFor="let forecast of this.weatherData?.forecast | keyvalue">
{{ forecast.value.date | date: 'MMMM d, y'}}
<div *ngFor="let history of this.weatherData?.historical | keyvalue">
{{ historical.value.date | date: 'MMMM d, y'}}
<div *ngIf="forecast.value.hourly[4].weather_code > 123 && historical.value.hourly[4].weather_code > 123;">
Adding text later here
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

There are two separate calls: one for forecast and one for historical. My challenge is setting conditions with both data sets at once.

Comment: Glad to see that you're moving with your forecast problem :). If i understand correctly are you trying to achieve make this div's visible whenever forecast and historical is not null or undefined. Am i right?

Comment: Hi again! :-) yes, it’s moving along. Gotta love StackOverflow for us learners out there. Sure we can go with “not null or undefined” for purposes of example. I’m really trying to hit both data sets (historical and forecast; they’re separate) in a single ngif.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is ;

````
<ng-container *ngIf="weatherData?.forecast && weatherData?.historical>
<div *ngFor="let forecast of this.weatherData?.forecast | keyvalue">
{{ forecast.value.date | date: 'MMMM d, y'}}
<div *ngFor="let history of this.weatherData?.historical | keyvalue">
{{ historical.value.date | date: 'MMMM d, y'}}
<div *ngIf="forecast.value.hourly[4].weather_code > 123 && historical.value.hourly[4].weather_code > 123;">
Adding text later here
</div>
</div>
</div>
</ng-container>
```
````

Comment: btw you don't have to use this. in html just write the variables name without this. => weatherData?.forecast

Comment: Ohh, so Ng-container will bring both together for the Ngfor? I’ll try this in a little bit when I get home.

Also, I saw you made that suggestion about “this.” on my other post, too. Thank you for catching that. The cleaner I can make this the better!

Comment: yes while program waits the condition you can also render an else template which says please wait or something you liked to show. I generally use ng zorro's spin component to provide better UX.  Also another suggestion, you shouldn't hold code in html, try to move them to a function in your ts which returns the result and use that fn in html. 

i recommend to use;

```
fnName(){
  return forecast.value.hourly[4].weather_code > 123 && historical.value.hourly[4].weather_code > 123;
} <= this condition has static variable. You should move this to enum

in html

<div *ngIf="fnName()">

Comment: Not working. The data is not displaying on the page. When I remove the ng-container it displays. But, the forecast data and historical data display at random. Not blended together.

`<div *ngFor="let history of this.weatherData?.historical | keyvalue">
    {{ history.value.hourly[0].precip }}
      <div *ngIf="history.value.hourly[4].weather_code < 123;">
      Adding text later here
        </div>
        </div>
    <div *ngFor="let forecast of this.weatherData?.forecast | keyvalue">
     {{ forecast.value.date | date: 'MMMM d, y'}}
      </div>`

Comment: it will flash the forecast data first on the page then historical and I believe that is because that what order the data is being called:
`getWeatherforecast(location) {
 return this.http.get(
"https://api.weatherstack.com/forecast?access_key=7d943ce723d7ddea226fd1806a40fb60&units=f&hourly=1&forecast_days=7" + "&query=" +
location
    );
  }
getWeatherhistory(date,location) {
 return this.http.get(
      "https://api.weatherstack.com/historical?access_key=7d943ce723d7ddea226fd1806a40fb60&units=f&hourly=1&historical_date=" + date + "&query=" +
        location
  );
 }`

Comment: it should've been work. Can you try to display weatherData.forecast and weatherData.historical before ng-container and check if they're both exists and still doesn't render ?

Comment: No good trying that. The data flashes and goes away. I need to wrangle this runtime somehow.